# Mongo find query is not working for certain values.

Tags: mongodb, boolean-expression

I have written a Mongo search query which includes an OR operator. Its boolean expression is as follows.

**A and (B or C)**
for the above layout of the expression, if one of **B** or **C** got false, it will return false. Hence my query fails. A more specific Mongo query is as follows.

```
{ "fieldName" : { "regex" : "AB.*" },
   "$and" : [[{"fieldName2" : "$in" : ["abc", "cds"]},
   "$or" : [{"fieldName3" : "$in" : ["abc", "cds"]}]]
}
```

In the above query, if `fieldName2` has one of `abc` either `cds` but `fieldName3` doesn't have any of that, then query returns false though it's in an **OR** clause.

So is there any other way I can implement this search query as in the mentioned expression or what I am doing wrong here. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$and` and `$or` apply their boolean operation over the contents of their array value. So your query should be rewritten as:

```
{
  "fieldName" : { "regex" : "AB.*" },
  "$or": [{"fieldName2" : "$in" : ["abc", "cds"]}, 
          {"fieldName3" : "$in" : ["abc", "cds"]}]
}
```

Note that you don't even need to use `$and` here because multiple query terms are implicitly AND-ed.

Comment: Is there anyway that we can right this using springdata mongo criteria ?

Comment: @JawadhSalihRifath I don't use spring so it would be best to post that as a new question, if needed.